# Web Audio API - Browser ogg vs Windows Media Foundation mp3

Tags: audio, web, mp3, ogg, ms-media-foundation

I'm playing with the Web Audio API in Firefox.
MP4 Videos play really nice in Firefox through Windows Media Foundation.
MP3 and OGG play also nice - but I wonder what what is better/faster or uses less
system resources for the audio stuff.
OGG with the browsers decoder or MP3 through Windows Media Foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the Windows Media Foundation decoder in Firefox, and I did a lot of the work in Firefox's Ogg decoder as well.

It probably doesn't make a big difference to performance whether you use Ogg or MP3 with the WebAudio API in Firefox.

*But*, MP3 isn't supported in Firefox on all platforms yet, not even all Windows versions yet. So you need to provide both Ogg/Vorbis and MP3 anyway if you want your webpage to work in Firefox on all platforms.

You can test if the browser you're running in supports MP3 (or Ogg/Vorbis) using the HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType() API.

If all goes well we'll have MP3 support shipping in Firefox on all tier-1 platforms by Q3 or Q4 this year.